# CSS image overlay effect with icon

Tags: html, css, overlay

I am currently trying to make an image overlay animation with icon slide in but not getting it how to perform in code. I can't find the method to apply the animation. I have insert link of type of animation I want.

Overlay animation demo:

[image: overlay animation link]

If anybody can make it, please help me. Below is the code I've tried so far:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


.xop-section {
 background-color: #EFEEEE;
 margin: 0;
}

.xop-grid {
 
  margin:0;
  padding:10% 0 10% 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content: center; 
}

.xop-grid:after {
 clear: both;
}

.xop-grid:after,
.xop-box:before {
content: '';
/* display: table;*/
}

.xop-grid li {
 width: 700px;
 height: 450px;
  margin: 30px 27px;
  padding: 0;
}

.xop-box {
 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out, ;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.xop-box:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 8px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.xop-img-1 {
 background: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/QQXLXMX04M.jpg);
  
}

.xop-img-2 {
 background: 
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/X8UKHZIPSB.jpg);
}

.xop-img-3 {
 background:
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/MQYJBYKTVK.jpg);
}

.xop-img-4 {
 background: 
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/T6OD5MKEY1.jpg);
}

.xop-img-5 {
 background: 
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/CG0HVMG2OF.jpg);
}

.xop-img-6 {
 background: 
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/NIRVEY04MU.jpg);
}

.xop-img-1 , .xop-img-2 , .xop-img-3 , .xop-img-4 , .xop-img-5 ,
.xop-img-6 {
  background-size: cover;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1111px){
  .xop-grid li {
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
  margin: 30px 20px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="xop-section">
  
  <ul class="xop-grid">
    <li>      
        <div class="xop-box xop-img-1">     
        <a href="#">
        </a>
          </div>      
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-2">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-3">
        <a href="#">

        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-4">
        <a href="#">

        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-5">
        <a href="#">

        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-6">
        <a href="#">

        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

After each of your anchor tags you can insert:

```
<div class="overlay">
  <span class='icon'>+</span>
</div>
```

The css below styles the overlay and the `+` symbol like you have it in the picture.

Check out this snippet. I've also posted a demo below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');
body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.xop-section {
  background-color: #EFEEEE;
  margin: 0;
}

.xop-grid {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10% 0 10% 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.xop-grid:after {
  clear: both;
}

.xop-grid:after,
.xop-box:before {
  content: '';
}

.xop-grid li {
  width: 700px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 30px 27px;
  padding: 0;
}

.xop-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.xop-box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.xop-box .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.xop-box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.xop-box .icon {
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 5px #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -2.5rem;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.8;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.xop-box:hover .icon {
  top: 50%;
}

.xop-img-1 {
  background: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/QQXLXMX04M.jpg);
}

.xop-img-2 {
  background: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/X8UKHZIPSB.jpg);
}

.xop-img-3 {
  background: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/MQYJBYKTVK.jpg);
}

.xop-img-4 {
  background: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/T6OD5MKEY1.jpg);
}

.xop-img-5 {
  background: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/CG0HVMG2OF.jpg);
}

.xop-img-6 {
  background: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/NIRVEY04MU.jpg);
}

.xop-img-1,
.xop-img-2,
.xop-img-3,
.xop-img-4,
.xop-img-5,
.xop-img-6 {
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1111px) {
  .xop-grid li {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="xop-section">

  <ul class="xop-grid">
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-1">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <span class='icon'>+</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-2">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <span class='icon'>+</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-3">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <span class='icon'>+</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-4">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <span class='icon'>+</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-5">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <span class='icon'>+</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-6">
        <a href="#">
        </a>
        <div class="overlay">
          <span class='icon'>+</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/ZJedWB)**

Comment: Thanks its excatly what i want. but how can i replace the plus icon with an fontawsome icon ` <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>`?

Comment: Just replace `<span class='icon'>+</span>` with `<i class="fa fa-eye icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>` - here's an updated **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/GvmWpJ)** - be sure to include the font-awesome dependency in your assets. Also as a side note, your design looks really nice :)

Comment: Ok but the cicle comes in everytime. how to remove it.

Comment: Whoops - I forgot to remove the border from the css - here it is now **[Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/GvmWpJ)**

Answer (score 0):

You can put position the transparent div inside of it absolutely with an opacity of 0 and add the same animations you used for your box shadow on it. Then when you hover over the transparent div, it will turn to .5 opacity. Same with the a link you can put inside and surround your icon.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


.xop-section {
 background-color: #EFEEEE;
 margin: 0;
}

.xop-grid {
 
  margin:0;
  padding:10% 0 10% 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
 justify-content: center; 
}

.xop-grid:after {
 clear: both;
}

.xop-grid:after,
.xop-box:before {
content: '';
/* display: table;*/
}

.xop-grid li {
 width: 700px;
 height: 450px;
  margin: 30px 27px;
  padding: 0;
}

.xop-box {
 
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out, ;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.transparent{
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out, -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out, ;
position:absolute;
z-index:10;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
display:block;
}
.transparent a{
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.transparent:hover a{
  color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.transparent:hover{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.xop-box:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 8px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.xop-img-1 {
 background: url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/QQXLXMX04M.jpg);
  
}

.xop-img-2 {
 background: 
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/X8UKHZIPSB.jpg);
}

.xop-img-3 {
 background:
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/MQYJBYKTVK.jpg);
}

.xop-img-4 {
 background: 
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/T6OD5MKEY1.jpg);
}

.xop-img-5 {
 background: 
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/CG0HVMG2OF.jpg);
}

.xop-img-6 {
 background: 
 url(https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/NIRVEY04MU.jpg);
}

.xop-img-1 , .xop-img-2 , .xop-img-3 , .xop-img-4 , .xop-img-5 ,
.xop-img-6 {
  background-size: cover;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1111px){
  .xop-grid li {
 width: 400px;
 height: 300px;
  margin: 30px 20px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="xop-section">
  
  <ul class="xop-grid">
    <li>      
        <div class="xop-box xop-img-1">     
        <div class="transparent"><a href="#">Icon</a>
          </div> 
         </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-2">
       
        <div class="transparent"><a href="#">Icon</a> </div>
       
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-3">
        <div class="transparent"><a href="#">Icon</a></div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-4">
        <div class="transparent"><a href="#">Icon</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-5">
        <div class="transparent"><a href="#">Icon</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="xop-box xop-img-6">
        <div class="transparent"><a href="#">Icon</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```